# How to add a key shortcut in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, shortcut, keyevent

New user: studying Java since January, I am using NetBeans right now, if I write this simple idea of shortcut I get tons of errors.

```
Scene root = new Scene(layout ,Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth()/2, Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight()/2);

root.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    public void handle(KeyEvent key) {

      if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.P && key.isControlDown()) {

          primaryStage.close();

      }
    }
  });
```

So the IDE just tells me I am doing almost everything wrong. On the line with setOnKeyPressed I get

**"type argument KeyEvent is not within bounds of type-variable T
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Event declared in interface EventHandler"**

I honestly don't know what T is.

Later, on getCode() I get the error **"cannot find symbol"**.

I imported everything and copied this code from another (presumibly working) question on stackoverflow.com I just want to press "esc" and make my primarystage to close if root is focused (or not, Im just trying to understand how to do it).

Googling this is very frustrating to me, I always get on this site with solutions that won't work or other sites where "listeners" or "key combinations" or "mnemonic" are created. I need to not use them in order to understand how Events are handled in this language, I know it can be possible but I cannot find a solution (even Oracle, nothing). The solution might be simple but I am going crazy searching for it

Comment: If you don't know what `T` is, maybe you need to learn about [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) in java.

Answer (score 1):

`T` refers to the type of the event handled by the event handler: see [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventHandler.html):

> Interface `EventHandler<T extends Event>`
>
> Type Parameters:
> `T` - the event class this handler can handle

Since `EventHandler` is declared with a type `T extends Event`, and the [`setOnKeyPressed()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#setOnKeyPressed(javafx.event.EventHandler)) method requires an `EventHandler<? super KeyEvent>`, you must provide an `EventHandler<T>` where `T` is some type that is both a subclass of `Event` (including `Event` itself) and a superclass of `KeyEvent` (including `KeyEvent` itself).

Since `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent` satisfies these constraints, and also since `javafx.sene.input.KeyEvent` certainly [has a `getCode()` method](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCode()) the only conclusion is that the `KeyEvent` type you're providing is not a `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent`.

In other words, you have the wrong import for `KeyEvent`.

Of course, you could just use Java 8+ compile-time type inference, and make all this go away, e.g. using lambda expressions:

```
root.setOnKeyPressed( key -> {

    if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.P && key.isControlDown()) {
 
        primaryStage.close();

    }
});
```

Now the compiler just infers that `key` is a `javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent`, and you don't even need the import.